# Subtract columns value in ascending order value of a column

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Have a dataframe mortgage_data with columns name mortgage_amount and month (in asceding order)

`mortgage_amount_paid = 1000`

mortgage_data:

```
name   mortgage_amount  month 
mark     400              1
mark     500              2
mark     200              3
```

How to deduct  and update `mortgage_amount` in ascending order or month using `mortgage_amount_paid` row by row in a dataframe
and add a column `paid_full` as yes if mortgage_amount_paid is fully deducted for that amount and no if not like this

mortgage_data:

```
name   mortgage_amount  month  mortgage_amount_updated  paid_full 
mark     400              1         0                     yes
mark     500              2         0                     yes
mark     200              3       100                     no
```

Comment: How did you got `100` in row `3`?

Comment: why last row is not fully paid? 400+ 500 + 200 = 1100 !!!

Comment: And how is the `paid_full` column calculated? You say "paid_full as yes if mortgage_amount_paid = mortgage_amount"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way :

```
import numpy as np
mortgage_amount_paid = 1000
df['mortgage_amount_updated'] = np.where(mortgage_amount_paid - df['mortgage_amount'].cumsum() >=0 , 0, df['mortgage_amount'].cumsum() - mortgage_amount_paid)
df['paid_full'] = np.where(df['mortgage_amount_updated'],'no','yes')
```

output:

```
>>>
   name  mortgage_amount  month  mortgage_amount_updated paid_full
0  mark              400      1                        0       yes
1  mark              500      2                        0       yes
2  mark              200      3                      100        no
```

Answer (score 1):

IIUC, you get the cumulative mortgage amount with `cumsum` and subtract the amount paid. Then filter this to get your columns:

```
total = df["mortgage_amount"].cumsum().sub(1000)
df["mortgage_amount_updated"] = total.where(total.gt(0), 0)
df["paid_full"] = df["mortgage_amount_updated"].eq(0).map({False: "no", True: "yes"})

>>> df
   name  mortgage_amount  month  mortgage_amount_updated paid_full
0  mark              400      1                        0       yes
1  mark              500      2                        0       yes
2  mark              200      3                      100        no
```